# Two same session_ids on two sites on different ii7 servers

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, ii6

I have a problem here.. i have site running on server A (with IIS7) and same site running on servers B (with IIS7).
Now if i goto my site from Server A and then goto the same site from Server B both the time i get the same the session id.

But when i got my sites set up on IIS6 i get different session ids no matter which iis6 server that i am going from .. which is desirable.

Is there some setting on IIS7 that i change or modify to get the same behavior?

Comment: What are you using for your session state manager?  IIS state server, SQL, In Process??

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like server A and server B have a common session state store, either IIS state server or SQL.